# failing to autofill fields with backing bean setter after failed submit/validation

Tags: validation, jsf, lifecycle, managed-bean

I want to automatically fill a form when a checkbox within it is activated using ajax (e.g. "Use billing address as delivery address?") and the backing bean's setter.

Therefore, the backing bean's setter for that checkbox' value sets the other fields and ajax has the whole form rerenderd. This works as long as no validators come into play. Now, I've had to to add a validator to some of the fields. When submitting the form in an invalid (empty in this case) state, the corresponding validation fails. If after that, the checkbox to autofill the form is checked and ajax submits the form again, only the validated form fields will be filled in when the form is rerenderd. All other fields remain empty, although the backing bean should have them set.

Why does JSF only render the backing bean values of the validated fields, after the validation failed once, but not the values of the other fields? Which logic in the JSF lifecycle is responsible for this behaviour?

Here's a small example:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TestBean
{
    private boolean toggle;
    private String stringValue1;
    private String stringValue2;

    public boolean isToggle() {
        return toggle;
    }
    public void setToggle(boolean toggle) {
        this.toggle = toggle;
        if(this.toggle) {
            this.stringValue1 = "Value1";
            this.stringValue2 = "Value2";
        }
    }

    // ... the usual getters and setters
}
```

And the corresponding jsf form:

```
<h:form id="testForm">
    <h:messages />

        <h:inputText value="#{testBean.stringValue1}">
            <f:validateRequired />
        </h:inputText>

        <h:inputText value="#{testBean.stringValue2}" />

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="toggleBox" value="#{testBean.toggle}">
            <f:ajax render="testForm" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="testForm" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

[first, the form is submitted without values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx0xW.png)

[then the checkbox is checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmPg8.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Leave getters and setters alone, use listeners.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse here... -_-

But I suspect you mean the action- and/or valueChangeListener described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnatn.html#bnats)?

I've added a valueChangeListener attribute to the checkbox and a method in the backing bean, which sets both of the other fields. The effect is still the same.

Comment: Check one of these for being a duplicate: https://www.google.com/search?q=fields+not+reset+after+validation+failed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this behavior occurs but adding components that are not refreshed properly (without validation) to `execute` looks like workaround.

```
<h:form id="testForm">
<h:messages />

    <h:inputText value="#{testBean.stringValue1}">
        <f:validateRequired />
    </h:inputText>

    <h:inputText id="stringValue2" value="#{testBean.stringValue2}" />

    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="toggleBox" value="#{testBean.toggle}">
        <f:ajax render="testForm" execute="@this stringValue2" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="testForm" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Also I suggest doing normal setter for `toggle`, `listener` for event and `action` in `h:commandButton` like this

```
<h:form id="testForm">
<h:messages />

    <h:inputText value="#{testBean.stringValue1}">
        <f:validateRequired />
    </h:inputText>

    <h:inputText id="stringValue2" value="#{testBean.stringValue2}" />

    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="toggleBox" value="#{testBean.toggle}">
        <f:ajax render="testForm" execute="@this stringValue2" listener="#{testBean.setValues}" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:commandButton action="#{testBean.formLogic}" value="Submit">
        <f:ajax render="testForm" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Lots of similar questions with explanation about possible causes: https://www.google.com/search?q=fields+not+reset+after+validation+failed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for breaking the etiquette here and essentially posting a question as answer, but the comments allow for too few characters for formulating the situation and my question after having a look at the google results you pointed me to.

BalusC wrote an article which is closest to explaining the jsf logic causing this effect: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2012/03/reset-non-processed-input-components-on.html

But there is still a detail, that I don't understand in the context of my example, when I consider the following points:

- The input components keep a submitted and a local value.
- As described in the link above - values in validated fields either stay as "submitted value" if invalid, or are set as "local value" of their component with the submitted value being set to "null".
- When rendering, jsf checks first the submitted value and then the local value for "null" and displays the first which is not null. Only if both are null the model value is rendered.

In my example, when I "execute" the whole empty form with the commandButton, the validation for the required field fails. Its value stays as "submitted value", in this case apparently null. There is no validation for the other empty field. Does it still distinguish between a local value and a submitted value? Does it set its local value to "empty" or "null"? Due to the validation failure the model is not updated and the form is being rendered with an error for the required but empty field.

Then another input is set, committed via ajax, misuses its setter method for setting the model values of the other inputs and renders the whole form again. During that rendering, the the previously invalid empty field seems to have both the submitted and local value set to "null", as the model's new value is being rendered instead of an empty field. The previously empty but not required field however, is being rendered as empty, although its value was just as empty or "null" as the validated field's one. If it had the submitted and local value set to "null", I would expect it to also display the model's value after the rendering.

Does the local value of the empty field actually distinguish between a previously submitted "empty" input and "null" when validation allows for an empty field or is absent? So during rendering, the empty local value is displayed again rather than the model value?